# Diagnosing high cpu load

Tags: sql-server

Let me start by saying our SQL servers are hosted by a third party. Every once in a while our monitoring software will show that cpu usage on one of our servers goes way out of line with normal activity, eg normal usage may be around 20% - 30 % utilization, jumping to 80% to 100% when the issue occur.

The other day I had this event occur for about an hour.

I confirmed it was sqlserv.exe hogging the cpu. No backups where occuring, no index maintenance jobs.

I set about running sp_whoisactive to see any problematic queries but there was nothing that seemed to burning a lot of cpu, nor did there appear to be lots of smaller queries - i just saw the usual amount of queries running then finishing.

Could it be possible that every now and again our cpu gets accidentally 'shared' out with other clients and that is what causes the high usage. Is this something that happens in the hosted world ?

To save my sanity, I run high cpu workloads on my test system, see the high cpu, capture the sql queires and plans using sp_whoisactive and am able to put 2 and 2 together.

Other times on our production systems I can see some problematic queries and am able to either stop them or fix them. Its just every now and again something seems to happen whereby I cannot see what is causing the high cpu - so i started to think about how our systems are hosted.

What questions should I be asking our vendor....if any at all ?

Comment: check [Troubleshooting SQL Server CPU Performance Issues](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/05/io-subsystem/cpu-troubleshooting) by Joe Sack. The methodology described is a good starting point to ensure that obvious points are not missed.